# Delphi, ALIGN in generated TLB files

Tags: delphi, activex

Searching for the errors in the 64 bit application found that that all TLB files generated by Delphi for accessing ActiveX libraries (e.g. ActiveDs or SpeechLib) have a lot of `{$ALIGN...}` directives and particularly `{$ALIGN 4}` which clearly makes the program to crash if it is a 64 bit app. On the other side Windows SDK files that provide the same c++ access do not contain any "align" word. Is this a Delph bug and I should replace all those directives or am I missing something and I should somehow handle them properly?
Here is the code from ActiveDs_TLB wrapper where it actually matters (actual value of `dwNumValues` can be found in `hReserved` place in a 64 bit app):

```
type
    {$ALIGN 4}
  __MIDL___MIDL_itf_ads_0000_0000_0001 = TOleEnum;
...
    ADSTYPEENUM = __MIDL___MIDL_itf_ads_0000_0000_0001; 
...
    {$ALIGN 4}
      ads_search_column = record
        pszAttrName: PWideChar;
        dwADsType: ADSTYPEENUM;
        pADsValues: ^_adsvalue;
        dwNumValues: LongWord;
        hReserved: Pointer;
      end;
```

Comment: @Tom Delphi version matters not - all modern Delphi as well as early post-7 generate the same TLB file.

Comment: I have just tested 64 bit tlibimp.exe - TLB file is produced the same, also there is no option regarding alignment

Comment: I don't think that what Tom is saying is really valid. You want to have the same import unit for 32/64 bit. You should get the same unit whether you import from the 32 or bit 64 dll. My question to you is why you feel that `{$ALIGN 4}` is responsible for your crashes. All the imported units for Office that are supplied with Delphi have `{$ALIGN 4}`. My best guess is that you have misdiagnosed your problem.

Comment: @David, yes I had the same thoughts and did the same things as you cause I use office wrappers too :). My opinion is that the errors are just hidden cause record types (where it really matters) are rarely used.

Comment: As per misdiagnosis I have an example of 100% sureness where it matters and causes different results - ActiveDs_TLB file (I don't know how to properly format code in commentaries)

Comment: If you are sure that the alignment is wrong, why don't you just fix it? And I presume that you used `sizeof` and `offsetof` in C++ code to diagnose this?

Comment: Yes of course I did and the problem is solved but so many ALIGN directives deliberately placed in different places made me wonder if I was wrong and just didn't properly handle them. Also what about other TLB files? Did the same thing to them either?

Comment: @David no, I didnt doubt TLB files (blasphemy) and just checked the same code in MSVC which worked perfectly no matter 32 or 64 bit app

Comment: You won't see ALIGN in a header file because that's not how it is done there. You need to check using `offsetof` and `sizeof` to be 100% sure.

Comment: You are right, never heard of 'offsetof', But '__declspec(align..' or 'alignas' should be found somewhere for sure, cause TLB files have very very lot of them with 2 4 and 8 value mixed sporadically

Comment: You sure? What about `#pragma`, or `#include <pshpack4.h>`. Header files can be a nightmare to parse manually. I'd always get the compiler to give a definitive verdict. At least for your own peace of mind.